# Salesforce Trigger to update the "Assigned To" equals "Created By"

Tags: android-activity, triggers, salesforce

I would like to use a trigger to update the "Assigned To" equals "Created By" on a newly created task.

Comment: What have you done or tried?

Comment: This sounds like a noble endeavor and we wish you the best. Go forth and make that trigger. Come back if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this assignment within trigger,

objTask.Owner = UserInfo.getUserId();

here owner refers to 'Assigned to' field